# Using Extension Methods to add DB/Webservice acces to a Domain Model

Tags: design-patterns, programming-practices

I just wondered if this would be a good practice:
Imagine a Model for example a User, which is read from a Webservice or an Database.
Of course the user-implementation must not have any knowledge about the datasource.
I wondered if it is an good idea to add those knowledge by an Extension method, so I could do something like this:

```
import NsOfExtensionmethod
var user = dataAccessInstance.getUser(id)
user.delete(dataAccessInstance)
```

Comment: and what is the actual difference compared to `dataAccessInstance.delete(user)`? The extension method even seems harder to read beacuse you have to see that its not a member method.

Comment: Questions containing the words "good practice" and "good idea" are unanswerable unless you define those terms within your specific project context.  We don't know what your specific goals are.

Answer (score 7):

This is an interesting idea, but there is one flaw with the design. A "data access" class is normally responsible for retrieving and persisting data, and the extension methods split this responsibility off. Furthermore, you aren't removing the dependency on the data access object, so you don't gain any flexibility there. As @Ewan pointed out in his comment, the static nature of extension methods prevents you from injecting mock object during unit testing, reducing the testability of your code, or at least making it more difficult to test.

This is precisely why the repository pattern is increasingly being used. This, plus using an interface to hide the implementation of the "data access" object allows you to utilize a database or a web service, and swapping out the implementation is as easy as writing a new concrete class.

Comment: I would clarify further that the static nature of the extension method vs a repository interface makes it harder to inject a mock datalayer into your code

Comment: @Ewan: I did update my answer with your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Mock objects are overrated.  The right idea should be to minimize their use by writing code that is easier to test, not encouraging their use by avoiding otherwise useful techniques.

Comment: Extension methods are really just syntactic sugar over static methods; static methods are the easiest of all methods to test, if you write them properly (avoiding state persistence between invocations).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Extension methods are also hard to test if you pass an instance of a concrete data access class that requires a database instead of passing in object by interface -- and mocking that object.